# Boto3: how to find security group id if I know group name

Tags: python, boto3

I am trying to find security group id by name. 
response = ec2.describe_security_groups() returns a data structure which includes all groups, ids and everything else. What is the way to filter group id for specific group if group name is provided?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace `GROUP_NAME` with the security group name you are looking for:

```py
import boto3


ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
group_name = 'GROUP_NAME'
response = ec2.describe_security_groups(
    Filters=[
        dict(Name='group-name', Values=[group_name])
    ]
)
group_id = response['SecurityGroups'][0]['GroupId']
```

Comment: I want to find same thing but using AWS CDK Typescript